# Google wants my phone number...?

Tags: gmail, google-account

I would do this - I mean, it already wants my name and birthday - but I don't have a phone, and I don't want to give it a fake number. It would be unfortunate for a complete stranger to get my email verification message.

Anyway, if there's no way to get around this, does anybody know an email provider that doesn't need your phone number?

Comment: As application recommendations is off-topic (see [help/on-topic]) for this site, you should probably rephrase your question to only include the part of registering a Google account without a phone.

Answer (score 0):

I have just tested creating a Gmail account and the phone number filed is not required when signing up with Google. The phone number filed can be left blank or if you are prompted for your phone number, at a later date, then a 'Skip' button is available at the bottom of the page. You can add an alternate email address if you have one in the event you need a password reset.